# Can you center the button?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

Help me to center the button below

Here is my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/bohdan-bohdan/pen/mdbeENZ).

don't know how to center the button

```
#form {
        display: grid;
        align-self: flex-start;
        margin: 0 7.5rem;
        width: 50%;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 2rem;
        grid-row-gap: 1.5rem;
        vertical-align: center;
        margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Center the buttons on the page? Center the text inside the button? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try doing this to center the button.

you need to set the `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` then set `justify-self` to center so that the button will be centered.

```css
button {
            margin-top: 3rem;
            justify-self: center;
            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 3;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Add next

HTML:
You can create a new div outside of #form:

```
<div class="button">
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
   display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin: 0 7.5rem;
     width: 50%;
}
```

then move your class buttons styles outside of #form

https://codepen.io/juricon/pen/PoYPmOE

Answer (score 0):

just Edit your button css to make it:

```
button {
   margin-top: 3rem;
   justify-self: center; /*Center Horizontally*/
   grid-column: 1/3; /*to take 2 columns*/
}
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/kareemda/pen/ZEzbVea)